# Homeomorphisms of quotient spaces. (With pictures)

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have a question about homeomorhic spaces: $\mathbb{R}^2$; $\mathbb{R}^2 /I$;  $\mathbb{R}^2/D^2$;  $\mathbb{R}^2/I^2$.

My attempt for first pair... I try to understand deformation of rectangular lattice via homeomorphism. Is my picture correct ($\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / I$)? How I can write expression for homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / I$ like $f(x,y)=\dots$?

[image]

Is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: I like your post, but this is a complex issue, you are asking two very different questions, and you should keep in mind our guideline to [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: Take $X=[0,1]$ , $A=\{0,1\}$, $B =\{0,1/2\}$. Are $X/A$ and $X/B$ homeomorphic? I am not sure but at first glance they don't look homeomorphic to me.

Comment: $I = [0,1]$? there is a problem of dimension for $\mathbb{R}^2/I$ or am I mistaken? Maybe it's $I \times \{0\}$

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal is with this question. You ask *How can I write expression for transform like $f(x,y)=...$*, but you do not give any clear statement regarding what properties you want this transform to have. Is your intention that this transform should be a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^2 / I$? If so, you should state that clearly in your post.